# Find the probability of pulling out 5 random products from the box and having among them at most two the faulty ones.

Tags: probability

There are 30 products in the box, from which 3 are faulty. Find the probability of pulling out 5 random products from the box and having among them at most two the faulty ones.

The denominator should be $\binom{30}{5}$.

How do you find the numerator for this question?  Is it $\binom{27}{3}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{27}{4}\binom{3}{1}$

The part $\binom{27}{3}\binom{3}{2}$ represents the event of picking 3 perfect products and 2 faulty products, while $\binom{27}{4}\binom{3}{1}$ stands for picking 4 perfect and 1 faulty product.

The probability in question will be $\frac{\binom{27}{3}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{27}{4}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{30}{5}}$

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: It's easier to calculate the probability of pulling out all 3 faulty ones and subtract from 1

Comment: Can you explain why does this work?

Comment: Because there are only two options: either you pull out all 3 faculty ones, or you don't (in which case you pull out at most two faulty ones) So, the probabilities of those two events add up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct, but you missed the probability of pulling out no faulty products. There are $\binom{27}5\binom30$ ways to do so, leading to a final probability of
$$\frac{\binom{27}{3}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{27}{4}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{27}5\binom30}{\binom{30}{5}}$$
Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, there are only three faulty products, so the complement of pulling out all three faulty devices can be taken:
$$1-\frac{\binom{27}2\binom33}{\binom{30}5}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I usually leave things out when counting.